# Is the product of two Zariski closed subgroups of $GL_n$ still Zariski closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $H, H' \subset GL_n {k}$ be two Zariski closed subgroups. Is the set $H H' = \{ h h' : h \in H, h' \in H' \}$ Zariski closed? Here $k$ is a field.

Same question for any (reductive?) algebraic group.

The counter examples I know to this claim in topological groups setting (where Zariski closed is replaced by closed) are distinctly non-algebraic, since these involve infinite discrete subgroups, or similar.

I guess a proof might be found by studying the action of $H$ and $H'$ on the ideals $I(H)$ and $I(H')$ through the regular representation. Maybe if $\rho_H$ is the (left) Reynolds operator for $H$, then $\rho_H(I(H'))$ should vanish on $HH'$, and similarly for a right reynolds operator for $H'$. Though for this we would need $H$ and $H'$ to be reductive to get these projectors, and I'm not sure how to argue further. These are the only ways I could think of right now to produce functions vanishing on $H H'$.

I guess that if true this is a standard fact -- a reference or hint would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is false. The simplest example I know is $n=2$, $B$ is a Borel subgroup (say, the upper-triangular one) and $B'$ is the opposite Borel. Then $BB'$ is dense in $GL(2,k)$ but is not the entire $GL(2,k)$. For instance, if $B$ is upper-triangular (and, hence, $B'$ is lower triangular), then none of the anti-triangular matrices
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&0
\end{array}\right]
$$
is in the product set $BB'$. The same happens in higher dimensions: $BB'$ is dense but is not the entire $GL(n,k)$.

I suggest reading Borel's "Linear Algebraic Groups".

Comment: Thanks - I should have thought of this since I did an exercise about the U^TDU decomposition of the open cell recently. I'll take a look at your reference. This definitely answers my question, but I'm wondering if the problem here is that the subgroup of upper triangular matrices is not reductive -- the defining representation is not completely reducible.

Comment: @AreaMan: I do not have an example but I doubt it is true for reductive subgroups (it is false for the product of 4 reductive subgroups).